# Asp.net mvc 4 merging two images

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a View where i am showing list of Images in Slider every thing is done in but want to code when user select two images the Controller should merge images with each other and also implement some text on both images.well is it possible in Jquery that it copy both divs and convert them to image and send to controller well.

any example 
C# 
Jquery Please let me know

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase Imageone, HttpPostedFileBase Imagetwo)
        {



            return View();
        }

  public static System.IO.MemoryStream CombineImages(byte[] imageBytes1, byte[] imageBytes2)
        {
            if ((imageBytes1 == null || imageBytes1.Length == 0) ||
                (imageBytes2 == null || imageBytes2.Length == 0))
                return null;

            //convert bytes to Image
            var image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes1));
            var image2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageBytes2));

            //create the Bitmap object
            var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            //create the Graphics object
            var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.High;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            g.DrawImage(image1, 0, 0);

            g.DrawImage(image2, 0, 0);

            var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bitmap.Width * bitmap.Height);

            bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            return ms;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't have to copy both the divs, assuming the images you have on the page are on your server you could simply ask the user for the two images and just upload the file paths as json and then retrieve them from the folder in the controller itself and go from there.